# Save as a random filename from a set list

Tags: vba, random, filenames

I'm trying to save a file but as a random name from a small list. This is what I have so far:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Public Sub SaveToDrive()

Dim categorys(5) As String
categorys(1) = "Adam"
categorys(2) = "James"
categorys(3) = "Henry"
categorys(4) = "William"
categorys(5) = "Keith"

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="e:\" & categorys(Int((5 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)).Name

End Sub
```

Currently, this returns an *Invalid Qualifier* error on "categorys" in the second to last line.

I'm completely new to VBA, but I was wondering if this was possible or if there was another/better way of doing it.

Thanks.

Comment: String do not have a Name property. Why do you have a `.Name` at the end of the line?

Comment: Probably because he is "completely new to VBA."

Answer (score 3):

See below for a working example.  A couple of notes:

- Arrays in VBA are 0-based by default.  This can be changed via `Option Base 1` or `Option Base 0` in the module header, but the safest approach is to simply specify both the lower and upper bounds when declaring the array (`Dim categorys(5)` --> `Dim categorys(1 To 5)`)
- Not sure what the purpose your `- 1 + 1` served so I got rid of it: `Int((5 - 1 + 1` --> `Int((5`
- I split up the expression and added some intermediate variables to make things easier to read and maintain going forward (`& categorys(Int((5 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)).Name` --> `Dim RandomIndex...`)
- Strings are not objects in VBA, so they cannot have methods or properties like `.Name`

---

```
Public Sub SaveToDrive()
    Dim categorys(1 To 5) As String
    categorys(1) = "Adam"
    categorys(2) = "James"
    categorys(3) = "Henry"
    categorys(4) = "William"
    categorys(5) = "Keith"

    Dim RandomIndex As Integer
    RandomIndex = Int((5 * Rnd) + 1)

    Dim FName As String
    FName = categorys(RandomIndex)

    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="e:\" & FName

End Sub
```